# There was an error in evaluating the test script: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: python, json, flask, postman

Im using Postman for the first time (newbie) with testing out a Flask App that accepts Json data and Postman keeps giving me this error `There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` but my Flask App seems ok. The Flask app accepts the Json and either returns a `200` or `400` and that seems to be working fine...

This is the Json I am sending to Flask thru the Postman console:
`{"Date": "2020-13-16T13:37:22.501743", "MeterReading": 5}`

Anything worrisome?? Any tips greatly appreciated..

In Flask I can save the data to sql which seems to be working OK `200` response.
`127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2020 11:39:24] "[37mPOST /dataear HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -`

***UPDATE FLASK APP CODE***

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template, jsonify, make_response
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dataear', methods=['POST'])
def getdata():

    r = request.get_json()
    if r.keys() == {'Date', 'MeterReading'}:
        try:
            df = pd.json_normalize(r)
            df = df.set_index('Date')
            #print(is_string_dtype(df.index))
            #print(is_numeric_dtype(df.MeterReading))
            if is_string_dtype(df.index) and is_numeric_dtype(df.MeterReading):# checker to verify MeterReading is numerical

                engine = create_engine('sqlite:///save_pandas.db', echo=True)
                sqlite_connection = engine.connect()
                sqlite_table = "OutsideTemp_MeterReading"
                df.to_sql(sqlite_table, sqlite_connection, if_exists='append')
                sqlite_connection.close()
                print("Data saved to sql!")
                return 'OK', 200
            else:
                print("rejected incorrect meter data unable to save data to SQL")
                return 'Bad Request', 400
        except:
            print("rejected incorrect date format unable to save data to SQL")
            return 'Bad Request', 400
    else:
        print("rejected incorrect keys for incoming json data")
        return 'Bad Request', 400



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

***Python CONSOLE RUNNING FLASK APP***

```
Incoming..
2020-06-17 11:39:16,024 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2020-06-17 11:39:16,024 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2020-06-17 11:39:16,027 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2020-06-17 11:39:16,028 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2020-06-17 11:39:16,030 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("OutsideTemp_MeterReading")
2020-06-17 11:39:16,030 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2020-06-17 11:39:16,038 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2020-06-17 11:39:16,040 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "OutsideTemp_MeterReading" ("Date", "MeterReading") VALUES (?, ?)
2020-06-17 11:39:16,042 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('2020-12-16T13:37:22.501743', 567234)
2020-06-17 11:39:16,046 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2020-06-17 11:39:16,055 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name
2020-06-17 11:39:16,057 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
Data saved to sql!
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2020 11:39:16] "[37mPOST /dataear HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

Comment: That error sure sounds like there's a syntax error in the python app code.  But you haven't shown us the code, so we can't help much.

Comment: Have you checked the webserver error log?

Comment: Ok ill show the Flask App code. Take it easy on me still learning the ropes :)

Comment: @JohnGordon I also posted the python console for hosting the flask app. The error only shows up in Postman console not Python...

Comment: What do you have in the Postman Test tab? The error is coming from there.

Comment: Ah ok its actually something unwanted.. Something from a tutorial.

Comment: shoot should I be using the `body` tab or `test` with Postman?

Comment: Thought it might be - it's probably got nothing to do with what you're actually doing but is causing issues still 

Comment: Yes if I just deleted out the `test` tab in Postman and only used `body` selected to `json` everything seems just fine... Geez

Comment: If you're Posting JSON then the body tab is what you need, the tests can help to confirm that the correct status code, Headers, data, etc are being used/returned from the endpoint.

Comment: @DannyDainton if you dont mind me asking is there anything funny with the way I am using `pandas` to create the sqlite db? Running some tests using Postman to make up some data and then checking the db using a db browser it seems to work Ok/data looks good...

Comment: Im hoping to use other developed pandas scripts I have for manipulating the data later on when I get that far :)

Comment: That's not something that I know anything about, I can answer anything you have related to Postman :D

Comment: Any chance you could give me a tip for this post? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451167/postman-testing-vs-real-test-sending-json-to-flask-server